# Simplify quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equatio $x^2+2x$ and the assignment is to simplify it.
So the way I would do it is to extract x $x^{2}+2x = x(x+2)$. Well this is fine but the correct answer is $x^{2}+2x = (x+1)^{2}-1$

I don't understand how $x^2+2x$ is simplified to $(x+1)^2-1$. Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: There has to be something more to this story.

Comment: $(x+1)\color{blue}{^2}-1 = x^2 + 2x \color{red}{+ 1 - 1}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completing the square

Notice that $(x + a)^2 = x^2 + 2ax + a^2 \Rightarrow (x + a)^2 - a^2 = x^2 + 2ax$

In your case, $a = 1$

$x^2 + 2x = (x + 1)^2 - 1$

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in your solutions. They were probably trying to get you to simplify it into some sort of standard form to help in plotting. The correct answer then is $ (x+1)^2 -1$.